# Java appengine.tools.cloudstorage missing GcsInputChannel in appengine-gcs-client-0.2.jar library

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to use Google Cloud Storage but are having a few problems.

So I decided to take it back to basics and try the simple demo com.google.appengine.demos for accessing the cloud storage.

I download the above jar library but

import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsInputChannel;

remains unresolved?

Looking in the library the following file exist

GcsOutputChannel.class
GcsOutputChannelImpl$1.class
GcsOutputChannelImpl$2.class

SimpleGcsInputChannelImpl.class
SimpleGcsInputChannelImpl$1.class

but no GcsInputChannel.class   ??????

Is this a simple omission? Is it me?? What am I doing wrong? Where else should I look?

Any help is gratefully received.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

OK I guess I was looking at old documents the file is in the download appengine-gcs-client-java-r65.zip